# Rank of matrix in case of homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, systems-of-equations

This is in reference to Theorem 4.8 in the pictures below. I am facing difficulty in understanding the proof of this theorem.

[image]

[image]

I am able to understand the proof upto the second last statement. What I am not able to understand is the logic behind the last sentence. I am facing problem to bridge the gap. I am fine with the statement that $\textbf{u}$ has to be independent of the row vectors because it is non-null and orthogonal to the row vectors. But how does this imply that the number of independent row vectors in $\textbf{A}$ is less than $n$?

Answer (score 0):

A non-null solution $u$ is orthogonal to all rows. The rows are in $\mathbb R^n$. If the row-rank was $n$, the rows would span $\mathbb R^n$ and there couldn't be any non-null vector orthogonal to them (because it would be orthogonal to $\mathbb R^n$). So, for the existence of a non-null solution it is necessary that the row-rank is $<n$. The claimed sufficiency in the theorem is not proved, though. But this is also clear: if the row rank is $<n$, the rows do not span $\mathbb R^n$ and you find a vector that is orthogonal to all rows, which will then be a non-null solution.

Comment: I am unable to understand this: "...and there couldn't be any non-null vector orthogonal to them (because it would be orthogonal to $\mathbb R^n$)." Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Assume the rows $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ span $\mathbb R^n$. Then any $x\in\mathbb R^n$ can be represented as $x = c_1a_1+\ldots+c_ma_m$. Now, if $u$ is orthogonal to all $a_k$'s, then $\langle x,u\rangle = \langle c_1a_1+\ldots+c_ma_m,u\rangle = c_1\langle a_1,u\rangle + \ldots + c_m\langle a_m,u\rangle = 0$. So $u$ would be orthogonal to each $x\in\mathbb R^n$. This can only be $u=0$.

Comment: "If the row-rank was n, the rows would span $\mathbb R^n$".  Are you referring to all the rows here or only $n$ rows. I am asking because $\mathbf{A}$ is of order $m\times n$. Also why do they span $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I mean all the rows of course. If the row-rank is $n$, then there are $n$ linearly independent rows (amongst the $m$ rows). And $n$ linearly independent vectors span an $n$-dimensional space. Since that $n$-dimensional space is contained in $\mathbb R^n$, it must be $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: "Since that $n$-dimensional space is contained in $\mathbb R^n$, it must be $\mathbb R^n$." Why is this so?

Comment: Also, one more question. In your answer, you have assumed "If the row-rank was $n$...". But isn't this applicable to any other number $\leq m$ also?

Comment: Why must an $n$-dimensional space $V$ in $\mathbb R^n$ be $\mathbb R^n$ itself? Well, let $B = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a basis of that space. If $V\neq\mathbb R^n$ you can extend $B$ to a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,w_1,\ldots,w_r\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$, where $r\ge 1$. But then the dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ would be $n+r\ge n+1$, a contradiction.

Comment: "If $V≠\mathbb R^n$ you can extend $B$ to a basis $\{v1,…,vn,w1,…,wr\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$..." Can you please explain this? I did not understand this.

Comment: No. This is basic linear algebra.